# Getting underestimated floating point factors

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding-error

Most physics engines support doing an object trajectory trace that will return a factor between 0.0 and 1.0 representing how far along an object's trajectory it will first hit an object.

The problem I'm concerned about is cases where moving the object by that factor of its trajectory results in its position being past the boundary it was supposed to hit and stop at (due to floating point rounding).

For instance, I created a C program that tried random cases until it ran into this issue, and came up with this example (although I've experienced ones with much less extreme movement, so it's not specific to large floating points):

```
float start     = 4884361.0f;
float wall      = 37961976.0f;
float end       = 1398674432.0f;
float time      = (wall - start) / (end - start);
float new_pos   = start + time * (end - start);
printf("We hit %f, but moving left us at %f.\n", wall, new_pos);
```

And this case prints out: `We hit 37961976.000000, but moving left us at 37961980.000000.`

So the position moved beyond the wall position and now the object is stuck inside the wall.

Is there a way to generate the factor or perform the factor multiplication such that the floating point error will always undershoot the actual value for all possible values?

Comment: Instead of changing floating point behavior, you might want to consider just writing a wrapper function which will take into account the limits when calculating new_pos.  Inside the wrapper, you can even promote to `double` and look at the error with greater precision there.

Comment: To paraphrase: you want to insure that roundoff errors are no higher than the exact values?

Comment: @cklink: That may be not be possible since in practice `time` is calculated by normal projections (since walls aren't necessarily aligned with the axes), so there's no real concept of a position limit at the time of calculating `new_pos`.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes. In the above example, the rounding error is in the calculation of `time` (since doing the exact arithmetic with that value results in an overshot value as well), so my question is whether there's a way to calculate `time` such that it'll guarantee no over-shoot.

Comment: You do realize that a 32-bit `float` only has about 7 significant (decimal) digits of precision, right? At least one of your constants has 10 significant digits stated, and so is going to run into problems immediately... Try replacing `float` with `double`. Even then you'll get roundoff issues, but they'll be much smaller...

Comment: @twalberg: I'm well aware that there will be errors, but as I mentioned in the question I've experienced cases with smaller numbers as well (in the 100s). The question is not how to avoid floating point error, but whether there's a way to ensure that the error will always be an underestimate of the exact value.

Comment: Try `float new_pos = start + nextafterf(time,0.0f) * (end - start);`.  Use the next smaller FP number for `time`.

Comment: A simple compare will do too.  `if (new_pos > wall) new_pos = wall;`

Comment: @chux: Comparison works here, but how I calculate time in practice may not allow me to do the same thing. `nextafterf` seems to make it behave, though, so thanks for that! It'd be nice to know whether I need to round down or not instead of always doing it, but I'll experiment with that function. I checked out the Quake 2 source code and it seems they 'solve' it similarly by subtracting 1/32 from the difference to the wall in the time calculation (since their positions are between -65535.0 and 65535.0, 1/32 is float epsilon). I'll accept if you post as an answer; it's the best yet, thanks!

Comment: Thanks - maybe in a bit - I'm hitting the road.  BTW: simple changing th FP rounding, see `FLT_ROUNDS` & `fesetround()` may work for you.  (only nominal experience on my part with that.)

Comment: Wow, even better! I'll have to think about whether I want to change the rounding behaviour of all of my code, but right now it seems that rounding towards zero fixes the above issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculated value is the next (or nearly the next) floating point number.  We are at the limits of `float` precision.  To insure an answer is at or to one side of the expected answer, there are a number of approaches

1) Higher intermediate precision: (should come up with the right answer far more often)

```
float start     = 4884361.0f;
float wall      = 37961976.0f;
float end       = 1398674432.0f;
double time     = ((double)wall - start) / ((double)end - start);
float new_pos   = start + time * ((double)end - start);
```

2) Logical: (this absolutely will work)

```
if (new_pos > wall) new_pos = wall;
```

3) Use a *slightly* lower time value: (a gentle hack)

```
float new_pos = start + nextafterf(time,0.0f) * (end - start);
```

4) Change FP rounding mode to round toward zero: (this may have a large impact though)

```
fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
```

5) A simple factor:

```
static const float factor = 0.99999;
float new_pos = start + factor*time * (end - start);
```

Lots of pros & cons per approach.

Comment: @Jengerer  Could also try a change of reference.  Make your `new_wall` 0.0 and `new_start = start- wall`.  Not sure how this may help but it does give increasing precision as you approach 0.0.

Comment: Thanks again. I think `nextafterf()` solves the problem well enough. I'd need a couple of years of computing to check that it works for all possible triples of float values for `start`, `wall`, and `end`, but it seems to work wonderfully with a smaller domain of possible values I tried. Since I know my time values will be between 0 and 1 I may just implement a quicker version of `nextafterf` that just decrements the int representation of the float by 1 (which is what `nextafter` does for that range of values).